# MDX Drillthrough subcube not working

Tags: ssas, mdx, drillthrough

I have a query as such

```
DRILLTHROUGH
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[#] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
{
  ( [Location].[Name].[Name].&[Test Location] )
}  ON ROWS
FROM (
  SELECT (
  { [v Item].[Item].&[Option 1], [v Item].[Item].&[Option 2], [v Item].[Item].&[Option 3] } ) ON 0
  FROM [TestCube]
)
```

Without the `Drillthrough` the query returns the correct results/cell; however, with the drillthrough the subcube

```
 SELECT (
      { [v Item].[Item].&[Option 1], [v Item].[Item].&[Option 2], [v Item].[Item].&[Option 3] } ) ON 0
      FROM [TestCube]
```

is completely ignored. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the ON ROWS.

Way to do this

```
DRILLTHROUGH
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[#] } ON COLUMNS
FROM (
  SELECT (
  { [v Item].[Item].&[Option 1], [v Item].[Item].&[Option 2], [v Item].[Item].&[Option 3] } ) ON 0,
  {[Location].[Name].[Name].&[Test Location]} ON 1
  FROM [TestCube]
)
```

Comment: is the subselect even required is this not possible with a WHERE clause?

Comment: This ` { [v Item].[Item].&[Option 1], [v Item].[Item].&[Option 2], [v Item].[Item].&[Option 3] }` breaks the drillthrough inside of a WHERE clause

Comment: I just a little surprised that the context of the subselect is available to the drillthrough - interesting behaviour.

Comment: Yeah...I fought with it for awhile. I guess it has trouble making slicer axis on its own in drillthroughs (when the same dimension is used more than once)